# How to calculate the cycles that change one permutation into another?

Tags: math, cycle, combinatorics, permutation

I'm looking for an algorithm that given two permutations of a sequence (e.g. `[2, 3, 1, 4]` and `[4, 1, 3, 2]`) calculates the [cycles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationCycle.html) that are needed to convert the first into the second (for the example, `[[0, 3], [1, 2]]`).

The link from mathworld says that Mathematica's ToCycle function does that, but sadly I don't have any Mathematica license at hand... I'd gladly receive any pointer to an implementation of the algorithm in any FOSS language or mathematics package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here http://www.codechef.com/problems/PCYCLE it only needs to be adjusted to remap the indices to the sorting order established by the second permutation...

Comment: Thanks for posting this link for your question. I am very interested to know how you adjusted the algorithm to convert from the first cycle into the second. I would be very grateful if you clarified more how exactly you mapped the indices

Comment: @Noah16 This was more than 9 years ago, so I cannot remember the details... But I think that what I meant is that you need to "normalize" the permutations. This would be renaming the numbers (or giving them an alias) so the first sequence is naturally ordered.

Comment: For my example in the question, we want `[2, 3, 1, 4]` to look like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` so we have a mapping `2:1, 3:2, 1:3, 4:4`, then after applying the mapping the second sequence would look like `[4, 3, 2, 1]` (that is, the indices of the numbers in the original sequence instead of their values).

Comment: After you run any of the algorithms that solve the finding cycles problems, you just apply the inverse mapping (to get the actual values instead of the indices).

Comment: I didn't understand this part: (then after applying the mapping the second sequence would look like [4, 3, 2, 1])....thanks in advance